# Windows Docker build logs

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In windows how do you output the entirety of `docker build...` to a log file? I need to troubleshoot a failed build from a docker file but the output in the command prompt rolls logs off.  I tried `docker build... > blah.log` but the output is not the same as the output in a CMD prompt.

Comment: `but the output is not the same as the output in a CMD prompt` in what way is it different?

Comment: @risail share the output file and cmd screenshots and what exactly is the different in both the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tool like GitBash.
After you can work like with Linux :

```
docker build . &> docker_build.log
```